# Display and play audio with python

Tags: python, fft, alsa, pyaudio

I am able to read audio files in `python`, with *alsaaudio* or *pyaudio*.

It is the same mechanism with these 2 libraries. I load data from wav file chunk by chunk in a loop. I write each chunk to audio device.

In my case, chunk size is 1024 bytes and my wav file has 16 bits per sample.

Audio is played, but now I want to display bar graph or VU meter.

Can I compute something in the loop without having a latency?

Thanks

Comment: You will always have *some* latency, otherwise it would be magic. The question is *how much* you are willing to accept. If you want to do non-trivial computations, you can move the audio data out of the loop with a queue. You can have a look at my examples [spectrogram.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/spectrogram.py) and [plot_input.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/plot_input.py).